# Linked List and sorting it alphabetically

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, alphabetical

I'm using a linked list to store structures. Each node has a structure called item_t. item_t has a field called name. I want to bubble sort the names alphabetically by swapping the items (item_t) in nodes. The algorithm works for numbers (ints, floats, etc) but gives incorrect results for strings.

I'm guessing the problem is hidden in incorrect use of strcmp but I read all the documentation and I can't see it.

```
typedef struct item_t
/*
 Definition of the item_t struct
*/
{
    char *name;
    float price;
}item_t;

/* structure for a node */
typedef struct node_t
{
    item_t item;
    struct node_t *next;
} node_t;

/* function to swap item of two nodes a and b*/
void swap(node_t *a, node_t *b)
{
    item_t temp = a->item;
    a->item = b->item;
    b->item = temp;
}

void bubbleSortByNameAscending(node_t *start)
{
    int swapped = 1;
    node_t *ptr1;
    node_t *lptr = NULL;

    /* Checking for empty list */
    if (start == NULL)
            return;
    while (swapped)
    {
        swapped = 0;
        ptr1 = start;

        while (ptr1->next != lptr)
        {
            if (strcmp(ptr1->item.name, ptr1->next-    >item.name) > 0)
            {
                    swap(ptr1, ptr1->next);
                swapped = 1;
            }
            ptr1 = ptr1->next;
        }
        lptr = ptr1;
    }

}

/* Bubble sort the given linked list */
void bubbleSortByPriceAscending(node_t *start)
/* TESTED */
{
    int swapped;
    node_t *ptr1;
    node_t *lptr = NULL;

    /* Checking for empty list */
    if (start == NULL)
        return;

    do
    {
        swapped = 0;
        ptr1 = start;

        while (ptr1->next != lptr)
        {
            if (ptr1->item.price > ptr1->next->item.price)
            {
                swap(ptr1, ptr1->next);
                swapped = 1;
            }
            ptr1 = ptr1->next;
        }    
        lptr = ptr1;
    }
    while (swapped);
}
```

Given this list:

1. List item
2. S7Edge 1500.00
3. iPhone7 1000.00
4. iOS10 0
5. Android 0

I'm expecting the following results when sorted by name:

1. Android 0
2. iOS 0
3. iPhone7 1000.00
4. iPhone8 2000.00
5. S7Edge 1500.00

But I'm getting this:

1. Android 0
2. S7Edge 1500.00
3. iOS 0
4. iPhone7 1000.00
5. iPhone8 2000.00
   I then added one more item that starts with Z just to get the sense of it:

   - Android 0
   - iOS 0
   - iPhone7 1000.00
   - iPhone8 2000.00
   - S7Edge 1500.00
   - Zoidberg 0

And I got:

- Android 0
- S7Edge 1500.00
- Zoidberg 0
- iOS 0
- iPhone7 1000.00
- iPhone8 2000.00

EDIT: I'm pretty sure 'i' != 'I', moreover 'Z' > 'i'. A logical solution would be to either lowercase or uppercase everything and then strcmp but how do I revert the changes back, so that "IPHONE" becomes "iPhone"?

Comment: You might want to use `stricmp` instead of `strcmp`, it ignores case when comparing. You are correct about the reason, in ASCII upper case letters come first

Comment: Note that `stricmp()` is the Windows function for case-insensitive string comparison.  The corresponding function on POSIX systems is [`strcasecmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcasecmp.html) from the header [`<strings.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/strings.h.html) (plural; the C header is `<string.h>`).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by duplicating the strings with names into temp variables, strupr() (makes the string capital) the temp variables and comparing them. I then swap the items in the corresponding nodes, works like a charm.

```
while (swapped)
            {
                swapped = 0;
                ptr1 = start;

                while (ptr1->next != lptr)
                {
                    char *temp1 = strdup(ptr1->item.name);
                    char *temp2 = strdup(ptr1->next->item.name);

                    strupr(temp1);
                    strupr(temp2);
                    if (strcmp(temp1, temp2) > 0)
                    {
                        swap(ptr1, ptr1->next);
                        swapped = 1;
                    }
                    ptr1 = ptr1->next;
                }
                lptr = ptr1;
            }
```